# The definition of $\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, math-history

When I taught my student the logarithm, he asked me about the historical definition of $\ln(x)$.

1. The first definition I found is that $$\ln(x)=\int_{1}^{x}{ \frac{dt}{t}  } $$
2. Defined as the logarithm to base $e$ or the inverse function of the exponentiation to base 
   $e$: $$\ln(x)=y \Longleftrightarrow e^y=x$$ where $e$ defined as
   $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$

Which is the real definition of the logarithm?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_logarithms

Comment: Neither is the "real" definition of the natural logarithm.  Or both are.  They are equivalent---you can start with either and get to the other (and there are other definitions, too, e.g. in terms of a power series).  Historically, it is likely that neither is the first definition to appear, either (Napier's tables are probably where logarithms get their modern start).  Pedagogically, pick the one that works best for your students, and which best matches with the background they have.

Comment: @XanderHenderson yeah i know , but my question is which of them is the first historical definition

Comment: You might get a better answer on [hsm.se]

Comment: As I said above, it is likely that *neither* is the first definition.  Read the Wikipedia article posted by @vadim123.  Also, it might be worth noting that there is a [History of Math and Science SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).  Arg!!!  In the time it takes me to find the link, quid show up!

Comment: Please edit your question rather than just clarifying it in a comment.

Comment: See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/42/which-came-first-the-natural-logarithm-or-the-base-of-the-natural-logarithm

Comment: @quid: good link, but some of the answers there are a bit deficient as they seem to confuse the natural logarithm with Napier's decimal logarithm. I think the ticked answer is fine.

Comment: @RobArthan to be honest I only skimmed the first answer there. I agree that not all answers there are very good.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no other possibility to the "History of Science and Mathematics" stackexchange site.

Comment: Qualitatively we look to answering..how many (integer or real)  times $n$  should $e$ be multiplied by itself to get $x$

Comment: @quid In simple, vadim123's comment is exact best solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on maths history, but logarithms are old enough not to have a "historical definition" that meets our standards of what a definition should be. I think the integral definition of the logarithm is the better one to teach, for a few reasons:

1. What is exponentiation? Even if you define $e$, that may instantly tell you $e^2$ or $e^{-\frac{1}{3}}$, but how do you tell what $e^{\pi}$ is? No combination of repeated multiplication, inversion, or taking roots of $e$ will produce this number. (Note, this can be mediated by defining $\exp(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$).
2. The indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is such a natural question that it warrants the invention of a function to fill the gap.
3. The log laws (and hence exponential laws) turn into lovely applications of various integral rules.
4. The calculus properties of $\ln$ and $\exp$ follow immediately from this definition too.

That's why I would teach the integral definition.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they call it a "logarithm" implies the must have had a concept that it is the logarithm of *some* base.  So when the *defined* they must have been using the concept $\ln x = y \iff e^y = x$.  And I even imagine they would be aware that $\frac {db^x}{dx} = C_b*b^x$ (for rational values of $x$; irrational values would have been poorly understood) so that would figure there must be a base so that $C_b = 1$ and $\frac {de^x}{dx} = e^x$.

But although that can be the *concept* and germination of a definition, it can't actually be a *practical* definition until *after* they had some way of finding what $e$ would be.  And I imagine to do *that* they had to recognize that $\int \frac 1x dx$ is a logrithmic function and the value of it's base would be $\lim (1 +\frac 1n)^n$.

So I would guess, it went in this order 1) $\frac {db^x}{dx} C(b)*b^x$ for some function $C(b)=\lim\frac {b^h - 1}h$.  2) That therefore $C(b) = \int_1^b \frac 1t dt$ and that $C(b)$ 3) the $e$ so that $C(b) = 1$ is $\lim(1 + \frac 1n)^n$ then 4) noting $\log_e (x) = C(x)$ is an immediate consequence and then the final definition 4) $\ln x := \log_e x = \int_1^x\frac 1t dt = C(x)$.

But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Guessing isn't very useful for determining the *actual* history...